# SQL datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I have data formatted "2009-07-17T00:00:00-05:00" in varchar variable. How can I convert this data to datetime field in MS SQL server using query or TSQL?

Comment: what's that last `-05:00`? some form of milliseconds?

Comment: are all the fields `like '%-05:00'`? Probably gonna have to convert to regular datetime using string functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008, you can use the `datetimeoffset` type:

```
select cast('2009-07-17T00:00:00-05:00' as datetimeoffset)
```

Since you are on 2005, `datetimeoffset` data type is not available for you. You should decide if you want to keep time zone information separately. If you just want the `datetime` part, just strip the time zone part from the string and cast it as a `datetime`:

```
select cast(left('2009-07-17T00:00:00-5:00', 19) as datetime)
```

Comment: somehow it's not working. shows "Type datetimeoffset is not a defined system type." What should I do?

Comment: What SQL Server version you're using? `datetimeoffset` is new in 2008.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1406.00 (X64)   Mar  3 2007 19:53:24   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 2):

Cast as DATETIME won't work, but that format is a valid XML datetime format, so you can route the cast through an XML type first:

```
declare @d varchar(50);
select @d = '2009-07-17T00:00:00-05:00';

select x.value(N'.', N'datetime') from (select cast(@d as xml) as x) as t;
```

Comment: yes. this data is from XML file. I used SELECT [StartDate] FROM
OPENXML(@iTree, '/List/DailyUpdate', 2) WITH ([STARTDATE] varchar(50)) any way to do it in SQL? I tried datetime it din't work...

Comment: Can you use XML methods instead of OPENXML? OPENXML is a dinosaur... Just say `SELECT xmlfield.value(N'(/List/Daily/Update)[1]', N'datetime') FROM table`. With OPENXML you need to use the WITH syntax to specify the schema of the return and map StartDate to datetime: `SELECT StartDate FROM OPENXML(...) WITH (StartDate DATETIME)`.

Comment: Also the query in the answer keep showing "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string." any idea ?

Comment: select x.value(N'.', N'datetime') from (select cast(@d as xml) as x) as t;

Comment: I tested my query on SQL 2008 before I posted, but indeed the SQL 2005 XQuery/XPath parser does not recognize the time zone info. Unfortunately that pushes you back to a solution based on string truncate, like Mehrdad suggested.